# When will a parametric solution generate all possible solutions?

Tags: number-theory, parametric

I was looking for integer solutions to this equation: 
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=3d^2$$
And found a parametric solution. Given r, s, t:
$$a=r^2+s^2-t^2+2t(r+s)$$
$$b=r^2-s^2+t^2+2s(t-r)$$
$$c=-r^2+s^2+t^2+2r(t-s)$$
$$d=r^2+s^2+t^2$$

My question is will this generate every possible solution?

Comment: no, it won't. A full parametrization would require four variables. $$ 1^2 + 5^2 + 11^2 = 3 \cdot 7^2 $$ But $7$ is not the sum of three squares

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1057093_parametrization_of_solutions_of_diophantine_equation_4_variable

Comment: If you scale your equation to _rational_ points that solve $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$, then ***yes***, it is the complete solution. See my answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ADDED: I found out how to prove this from one of my favorite papers, [Jones and Pall (1939)](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Jones_Pall_1939.pdf), the discussion of quaternions in manuscript pages 174-176. First,  a "pure quaternion" $w$ means that the real part zero, so such a $w = w_1 i + w_2 j + w_3 k.$ "Proper" means the greatest common divisor of the coefficients is $1.$ If we have a pure quaternion $w$ with norm $Nw = 3,$ there is a unit $\theta$ such that either $\bar{\theta} w \theta = i + j + k$ or   $\bar{\theta} w \theta = -(i + j + k).$

Next, suppose we have a proper pure quaternion $v$ with $Nv = 3 m^2,$ with odd positive integer $m.$ By Theorem 2 on page 175 we may define right divisor $q$ with $Nq = m,$ so $v = pq.$ Note $Np = 3m.$

Repeating Theorem 2, we may set $p = s r$ with $Ns = m.$ So far, $v = s r q.$

This is the cute part, from the proof of Theorem 3 on page 176. Since $v$ is pure, $\bar{v} = -v.$ However, $-v = \bar{v} = \bar{q} \bar{r} \bar{s}.$ That is, $\bar{q}$ is a left divisor of $-v$ and of $v.$ By theorem 2, there is a unit $\theta$ such that $$ s = \bar{q} \theta. $$

We have reached $$ v =  \bar{q} \theta r q. $$ It follows that
$\theta r$ is a pure quaternion of norm $3.$ There is a further unit $\omega$ such that $q = \omega p$ and
$$ v = \pm \, \bar{p} \, (i+j+k) \, p. $$ Negating $v$ does not change its norm.

Saturday morning, 15 October 2016: I finally figured out how to get the computer to print each (ordered) quadruple just once. Take all $a \geq b \geq c \geq 0$ OR $a \leq b \leq c \leq 0.$ This is legitimate, my little proof above says the central element in the product is one of $\pm(i+j+k).$  This still gives two representations each, some $(w,x,y,z)$ and $(-w,-x,-y,-z),$ so I said to take the ordered quadruple (WLOG) with $w > 0$ or $w = 0, x > 0,$ or $w=0, x=0, y > 0,$ or $w = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z > 0.$ Very satisfying outcome.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

This is the right way to do this and get everything primitive. Take the quaternion $q = w + x i + y j + z k,$ so that  $\bar{q} = w - x i - y j - z k.$ We get a "vector" or "pure quaternion," meaning a quaternion with real part zero, from
$$  \bar{q} \, (i+j+k) \, q =  ai + bj + ck.  $$ It is automatic that
$$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 3 (w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2. $$
I will see if I can  find a reference that proves that all possibilities with $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ occur this way. As you can see from the output, they are repeated in different orders and with different $\pm$ signs. I think I will leave in the zeros in the formulas for $a,b,c.$ They serve as spacers.

$$ a = w^2 + x^2 - y^2 - z^2 + 0 \, w  x - 2  w  y + 2  x  y + 2  w  z + 2  x  z + 0  \,  y  z $$
$$ b = w^2 - x^2 + y^2 - z^2 + 2  w  x - 0  \,  w  y + 2  x  y - 2  w  z + 0  \,  x  z + 2  y  z$$
$$ c = w^2 - x^2 - y^2 + z^2 - 2  w  x + 2  w  y + 0  \,  x  y + 0  \,  w  z + 2  x  z + 2  y  z$$
$$ d = w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 $$

Sunday 16 October: all three indefinite forms $a,b,c$ are integrally equivalent, in $SL_4 \mathbb Z,$ to the diagonal form $$p^2 + q^2 - 3s^2 - 3 t^2$$
with Gram matrix
$$
D =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Indeed, if
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right),
\; \; \; \;  A^T D A =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right).
$$
The rows of $A$ tell us that 
$$ a = (w - y + z)^2 + (x+y+z)^2 - 3 y^2 - 3 z^2, $$ compare
$$ a = w^2 + x^2 - y^2 - z^2 + 0 \, w  x - 2  w  y + 2  x  y + 2  w  z + 2  x  z + 0  \,  y  z. $$

If
$$
B =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right),
\; \; \; \;  B^T D B =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{array}
\right),
$$
The rows of $B$ tell us that 
$$ b = (w +x - z)^2 + (x+y+z)^2 - 3 (-x)^2 - 3 z^2, $$
where the minus sign on the singleton $x$ has no effect other than $ \det B = 1.$ Compare
$$ b = w^2 - x^2 + y^2 - z^2 + 2  w  x - 0  \,  w  y + 2  x  y - 2  w  z + 0  \,  x  z + 2  y  z.$$

If
$$
C =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right),
\; \; \; \;  C^T D C =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
\right).
$$
The rows of $C$ tell us that 
$$ c = (w - x + y)^2 + (x+y+z)^2 - 3 y^2 - 3 (-x)^2 $$
where the minus sign on the singleton $x$ has no effect except $\det C =1.$ Compare
$$ c = w^2 - x^2 - y^2 + z^2 - 2  w  x + 2  w  y + 0  \,  x  y + 0  \,  w  z + 2  x  z + 2  y  z.$$

Your suggested solution seems pretty similar to the result of taking $w = 0,$ then negating $a,b,c,$ because mine have two minus signs remaining on the squares.

---

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pythagorean_Quadruples 1 25 | sort -n
    1       1    1    1   check  0 w x y z      1    0    0    0
    3      -5   -1   -1   check  0 w x y z      0    1   -1   -1
    5      -7   -5   -1   check  0 w x y z      0    1    0   -2
    7      11    5    1   check  0 w x y z      1    2    1    1
    9      11   11    1   check  0 w x y z      0    2    2    1
    9     -13   -7   -5   check  0 w x y z      0    2   -1   -2
   11     -13  -13   -5   check  0 w x y z      0    1    1   -3
   11      17    7    5   check  0 w x y z      3    1    0    1
   11      19    1    1   check  0 w x y z      3    0   -1    1
   13     -17  -13   -7   check  0 w x y z      0    2    0   -3
   13      19   11    5   check  0 w x y z      2   -2   -2   -1
   15      19   17    5   check  0 w x y z      3    2    1    1
   15     -23  -11   -5   check  0 w x y z      1   -1    3   -2
   15      25    7    1   check  0 w x y z      1   -3   -2   -1
   17     -23  -13  -13   check  0 w x y z      0    3   -2   -2
   17      23   17    7   check  0 w x y z      4    0   -1    0
   17      25   11   11   check  0 w x y z      0    3    2    2
   17      29    5    1   check  0 w x y z      3   -2   -2    0
   19     -23  -23   -5   check  0 w x y z      1   -3    3    0
   19     -25  -17  -13   check  0 w x y z      0    3   -1   -3
   19     -29  -11  -11   check  0 w x y z      1    0    3   -3
   19     -31  -11   -1   check  0 w x y z      1    1    1   -4
   21     -25  -23  -13   check  0 w x y z      0    2    1   -4
   21      29   19   11   check  0 w x y z      2    3    2    2
   21      31   19    1   check  0 w x y z      4    2    0    1
   23      29   25   11   check  0 w x y z      1   -3   -3   -2
   23      31   25    1   check  0 w x y z      3   -2   -3   -1
   23     -35  -19   -1   check  0 w x y z      1   -3    3    2
   23      37   13    7   check  0 w x y z      3    3    1    2
   25     -31  -25  -17   check  0 w x y z      0    3    0   -4
   25      35   19   17   check  0 w x y z      4   -2   -2   -1
   25     -35  -23  -11   check  0 w x y z      1   -2    4   -2
   25      41   13    5   check  0 w x y z      1    4    2    2
   25     -43   -5   -1   check  0 w x y z      2   -1    4   -2
```

---

Comment: If we consider rational points on $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$, then yes, the OP's version, modified slightly, is the complete rational solution.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII sure. However, in attempting to select the primitive integral solutions, there is no joy. There is a good reason that pythagorean quadruples are usually parametrized by the four variable formula attributed to V. A. Lebesgue (although Euler would have known of it). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple

Comment: I happened to catch a glimpse of a paper. Although the solutions given in the paper are not complete, the paper provides a geometric intuition. http://emis.math.tifr.res.in/journals/JIS/VOL10/Ionascu/ionascu2.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it. The complete ***rational*** parameterization to
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=3\tag1$$
is given by,
$$a=\frac{r^2+s^2-t^2-2t(r+s)}{r^2+s^2+t^2}\\b=\frac{r^2-s^2+t^2-2s(r+t)}{r^2+s^2+t^2}\\c=\frac{-r^2+s^2+t^2-2r(s+t)}{r^2+s^2+t^2}\tag2$$
***Proof:*** For any solution $a,b,c$, one can find $r,s,t$ using the simple formulas,
$$r=\frac{1}{b-1}\\s=\frac{1}{c-1}\\t=\frac{a-1}{(b-1)(c-1)}\tag3$$
***Example:*** Using Jagy's example, we have $a,b,c = \frac{1}{7}, \frac{5}{7}, 
\frac{11}{7}$. Plugging this into $(3)$, we get $r,s,t = \frac{-7}{2}, \frac{7}{4}, \frac{21}{4}$. Plugging this into $(2)$, we recover the $a,b,c$.

Note: Division by zero is easily avoided by using $(\pm1)^2+(\pm1)^2+(\pm1)^2=3$.