# Find all $x,y,z$ such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3^{10}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, p-adic-number-theory, sums-of-squares

By Legendre's [3-squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_three-square_theorem) theorem, a number $n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ can be written as the sum of three squares if $n \neq 4^a(8b+7)$.  In my case, I am choosing $$n = 3^{10} \equiv (3^2)^5 \equiv 1 \mod 8$$
which is safe.  In that case, is there any way I can find these integers by induction?  Perhaps I can try:
$$ 3 = 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 $$
This is encouraging to let's try the case of $n=9$:  That is even easier since it is a perfect square:
$$ 9 = 3^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 $$
Let's take it one step further.  $n = 3^3 = 27$.  There is no way to combine my previous two answers to get a third solution.  However, by searching:
$$ 27 = 5^2 + 1^2 + 1^2  = 3^2 + 3^2 + 3^2$$
and $n = 81 = 3^4$ is another perfect square (in fact a perfect 4th power) but there may be other solutions:
$$ 81 = 9^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = \dots $$
Is it possible to get all the way to $n = 3^{10}$ in this manner.  Is there an inductive approach to solving:
$$ 3^n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 $$
for all **odd** and **even** powers $n$ ?

Comment: Arithmetical structure of sums of three squares is much more complicated than it is for two or four squares. I personally doubt a simple method of enumerating solutions exists, even in such specific cases, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I gave the method for  $$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 3 m^2 $$  at [When will a parametric solution generate all possible solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964607/when-will-a-parametric-solution-generate-all-possible-solutions)

Very proud of that one, I had not been sure how to tweak Jones and Pall, turns out there is no problem since we need only express the $3$ as the norm of either quaternion $i+j+k$ or of $-i-j-k,$ so there is no loss in just taking the first and saying that we could negate $a,b,c$ without harming anything.

Given **odd** positive $m,$ all **primitive** solutions to $$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = m^2 $$ come from first finding all
$$ w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = m, $$ then writing out Lebesgue's (V. A. Lebesgue) formula ,
$$ a = w^2 + x^2 - y^2 - z^2, $$
$$ b = 2(wz+xy), $$
$$ c = 2(-wy + xz).  $$
A complete discussion is Theorem 3 of [Jones and Pall](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Jones_Pall_1939.pdf)

Well.  Easy enough to program what is often called Lebesgue's identity. Here are all primitive solutions for $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 3 m^2,$ for $m = 1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243.$ I take $a,b,c$ either all positive or all negative, $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ as I mentioned, and $|a| \geq |b| \geq |c|.$ All are odd, of course, check mod 8.

```
    1       1    1    1   check  0 w x y z      1    0    0    0
    3      -5   -1   -1   check  0 w x y z      0    1   -1   -1
    9      11   11    1   check  0 w x y z      0    2    2    1
    9     -13   -7   -5   check  0 w x y z      0    2   -1   -2
   27     -35  -29  -11   check  0 w x y z      1   -3    4   -1
   27     -35  -31   -1   check  0 w x y z      1   -1    3   -4
   27      37   23   17   check  0 w x y z      5    1    0    1
   27      43   13   13   check  0 w x y z      5    0   -1    1
   27     -43  -17   -7   check  0 w x y z      1   -3    4    1
   81     103   85   43   check  0 w x y z      2    6    5    4
   81    -103  -95   -7   check  0 w x y z      1    0    4   -8
   81    -113  -83   -5   check  0 w x y z      2   -6    5    4
   81     115   77   23   check  0 w x y z      6   -4   -5   -2
   81    -121  -71   -1   check  0 w x y z      0    4   -1   -8
   81     125   47   43   check  0 w x y z      6    5    2    4
   81    -127  -55  -23   check  0 w x y z      1    4    0   -8
   81    -131  -41  -29   check  0 w x y z      2    3    2   -8
   81     131   49   11   check  0 w x y z      4   -6   -5   -2
   81     133   37   25   check  0 w x y z      5    6    2    4
   81     137   25   17   check  0 w x y z      7   -4   -4    0
   81     139   19    1   check  0 w x y z      8    2   -2    3
   81      91   89   59   check  0 w x y z      8   -2   -3   -2
   81     -95  -73  -73   check  0 w x y z      0    7   -4   -4
  243    -257 -253 -217   check  0 w x y z      0    7    5  -13
  243    -263 -263 -197   check  0 w x y z      1  -11   11    0
  243    -265 -241 -221   check  0 w x y z      0   11   -1  -11
  243     271  245  209   check  0 w x y z      9    8    7    7
  243     283  263  167   check  0 w x y z     12    7    5    5
  243    -289 -251 -175   check  0 w x y z      1  -12    7    7
  243    -295 -241 -179   check  0 w x y z      1    3    8  -13
  243     299  239  175   check  0 w x y z      8    9    7    7
  243     299  289   65   check  0 w x y z     15    4   -1    1
  243     301  211  205   check  0 w x y z      7   -9   -8   -7
  243     301  289   55   check  0 w x y z     11    9    5    4
  243    -305 -211 -199   check  0 w x y z      1    8    3  -13
  243    -307 -283  -53   check  0 w x y z      3  -11    7    8
  243     307  287   23   check  0 w x y z      4   11    9    5
  243     311  265  101   check  0 w x y z     13   -4   -7   -3
  243     317  257  103   check  0 w x y z     13    7    3    4
  243    -319 -269  -55   check  0 w x y z      3  -11    8    7
  243     341  215  121   check  0 w x y z      3   11    8    7
  243    -341 -245  -29   check  0 w x y z      4   -5   11   -9
  243    -349 -235  -11   check  0 w x y z      1   -8    3   13
  243     353  167  157   check  0 w x y z      3  -11   -8   -7
  243     353  223   53   check  0 w x y z     15    1   -4    1
  243    -355 -191 -121   check  0 w x y z      3   -7   13   -4
  243    -359 -205  -79   check  0 w x y z      3    1    8  -13
  243    -361 -155 -151   check  0 w x y z      3   -4   13   -7
  243     361  199   85   check  0 w x y z     11   -7   -8   -3
  243     365  179  109   check  0 w x y z     15   -1   -4    1
  243     371  191   55   check  0 w x y z      4  -11   -9   -5
  243    -373 -163 -107   check  0 w x y z      3   -8   13   -1
  243    -377 -187   -7   check  0 w x y z      5   -4   11   -9
  243     383  133  113   check  0 w x y z      1   12    7    7
  243    -383 -173  -23   check  0 w x y z      5   -5   12   -7
  243     385  169   19   check  0 w x y z      5  -11   -9   -4
  243    -389 -125 -101   check  0 w x y z      4    3    7  -13
  243    -389 -151  -55   check  0 w x y z      1    8   -3  -13
  243     397  133   43   check  0 w x y z     13   -5   -7    0
  243     403   97   73   check  0 w x y z      5   12    5    7
  243     407  107    7   check  0 w x y z      0   13    7    5
  243     409   95   29   check  0 w x y z      7  -11   -8   -3
  243    -419  -31  -25   check  0 w x y z      3   -7   13    4
  243     419   35   19   check  0 w x y z     12   -7   -7    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope you don’t mind, but I’ll rewrite your equation as
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=n=3^q$$
as you’ve given two meanings to $n$.

I’ll show all solutions in the form $(q,n,x,y,z)$

You found $(1,3,1,1,1)$, which, basically, states that $3*k^2=(k^2+k^2+k^2)$, giving,
$$(3,27,3,3,3)$$
$$(5,243,9,9,9)$$
$$(7,2187,27,27,27)$$
$$(9,19683,81,81,81)$$

$(2a+1,3^{2a+1},3^a,3^a,3^a)$ with $a>=0$

You also found $(2,9,3,0,0)$, so multiplying by a constant gives
$$(2,9,3,0,0)$$
$$(4,81,9,0,0)$$
$$(6,729,27,0,0)$$
$$(8,6561,81,0,0)$$
$$(10,59049,243,0,0)$$

$(2b,3^{2b},3^b,0,0)$ with $b>0$

There is a standard parametric solution for the sum of three (or more) squares equal to a square. In the notation of this problem, an existing solution $(q,n,x,y,z)$ gives a new solution, $(Q,N,X,Y,Z)$
$$Q=2q$$
$$N=3^Q$$
$$X=Abs(-x^2+y^2+z^2)$$
$$Y=2*x*y$$
$$Z=2*x*z$$

Because the values of $(x,y,z)$ are interchangeable, changing the order of the values gives up to two further solutions

Applying this to $(1,3,1,1,1)$ gives $(2,9,2,2,1)$.
Feeding this new solution in gives $(4,81,8,4,1)$ and $(4,81,7,4,4)$, and so on.

Now I’m almost certain there are other patterns to be seen, to generate parametric solutions and methods, but fear they will never be able to form a full list.
Sadly, I don’t have the time to keep looking in the next week.

However, the effort to code a program is tiny, so perhaps this $(q,n,x,y,z)$ list will help.

$$(1,3,1,1,1)$$
$$(2,9,2,2,1)$$
$$(2,9,3,0,0)$$
$$(3,27,3,3,3)$$
$$(3,27,5,1,1)$$
$$(4,81,6,6,3)$$
$$(4,81,7,4,4)$$
$$(4,81,8,4,1)$$
$$(4,81,9,0,0)$$
$$(5,243,9,9,9)$$
$$(5,243,11,11,1)$$
$$(5,243,13,7,5)$$
$$(5,243,15,3,3)$$
$$(6,729,18,18,9)$$
$$(6,729,21,12,12)$$
$$(6,729,22,14,7)$$
$$(6,729,23,10,10)$$
$$(6,729,23,14,2)$$
$$(6,729,24,12,3)$$
$$(6,729,25,10,2)$$
$$(6,729,26,7,2)$$
$$(6,729,27,0,0)$$
$$(7,2187,27,27,27)$$
$$(7,2187,33,33,3)$$
$$(7,2187,35,29,11)$$
$$(7,2187,35,31,1)$$
$$(7,2187,37,23,17)$$
$$(7,2187,39,21,15)$$
$$(7,2187,43,13,13)$$
$$(7,2187,43,17,7)$$
$$(7,2187,45,9,9)$$
$$(8,6561,54,54,27)$$
$$(8,6561,55,44,40)$$
$$(8,6561,56,49,32)$$
$$(8,6561,56,55,20)$$
$$(8,6561,56,56,17)$$
$$(8,6561,63,36,36)$$
$$(8,6561,64,41,28)$$
$$(8,6561,64,44,23)$$
$$(8,6561,64,47,16)$$
$$(8,6561,64,49,8)$$
$$(8,6561,65,44,20)$$
$$(8,6561,66,42,21)$$
$$(8,6561,68,41,16)$$
$$(8,6561,68,44,1)$$
$$(8,6561,69,30,30)$$
$$(8,6561,69,42,6)$$
$$(8,6561,72,36,9)$$
$$(8,6561,75,30,6)$$
$$(8,6561,76,23,16)$$
$$(8,6561,76,28,1)$$
$$(8,6561,78,21,6)$$
$$(8,6561,79,16,8)$$
$$(8,6561,81,0,0)$$
$$(9,19683,81,81,81)$$
$$(9,19683,91,89,59)$$
$$(9,19683,95,73,73)$$
$$(9,19683,99,99,9)$$
$$(9,19683,103,85,43)$$
$$(9,19683,103,95,7)$$
$$(9,19683,105,87,33)$$
$$(9,19683,105,93,3)$$
$$(9,19683,111,69,51)$$
$$(9,19683,113,83,5)$$
$$(9,19683,115,77,23)$$
$$(9,19683,117,63,45)$$
$$(9,19683,121,71,1)$$
$$(9,19683,125,47,43)$$
$$(9,19683,127,55,23)$$
$$(9,19683,129,39,39)$$
$$(9,19683,129,51,21)$$
$$(9,19683,131,41,29)$$
$$(9,19683,131,49,11)$$
$$(9,19683,133,37,25)$$
$$(9,19683,135,27,27)$$
$$(9,19683,137,25,17)$$
$$(9,19683,139,19,1)$$
$$(10,59049,154,143,122)$$
$$(10,59049,158,134,127)$$
$$(10,59049,158,146,113)$$
$$(10,59049,162,162,81)$$
$$(10,59049,165,132,120)$$
$$(10,59049,168,147,96)$$
$$(10,59049,168,165,60)$$
$$(10,59049,168,168,51)$$
$$(10,59049,178,127,106)$$
$$(10,59049,178,134,97)$$
$$(10,59049,178,158,49)$$
$$(10,59049,178,161,38)$$
$$(10,59049,182,130,95)$$
$$(10,59049,182,143,74)$$
$$(10,59049,182,145,70)$$
$$(10,59049,182,154,47)$$
$$(10,59049,182,158,31)$$
$$(10,59049,182,161,2)$$
$$(10,59049,189,108,108)$$
$$(10,59049,190,118,95)$$
$$(10,59049,190,143,50)$$
$$(10,59049,192,123,84)$$
$$(10,59049,192,132,69)$$
$$(10,59049,192,141,48)$$
$$(10,59049,192,147,24)$$
$$(10,59049,193,130,70)$$
$$(10,59049,193,134,62)$$
$$(10,59049,193,146,22)$$
$$(10,59049,195,132,60)$$
$$(10,59049,198,126,63)$$
$$(10,59049,202,97,94)$$
$$(10,59049,202,113,74)$$
$$(10,59049,202,127,46)$$
$$(10,59049,202,134,17)$$
$$(10,59049,204,123,48)$$
$$(10,59049,204,132,3)$$
$$(10,59049,206,113,62)$$
$$(10,59049,206,127,22)$$
$$(10,59049,207,90,90)$$
$$(10,59049,207,126,18)$$
$$(10,59049,209,118,38)$$
$$(10,59049,209,122,22)$$
$$(10,59049,214,97,62)$$
$$(10,59049,214,113,22)$$
$$(10,59049,216,108,27)$$
$$(10,59049,218,95,50)$$
$$(10,59049,218,97,46)$$
$$(10,59049,218,106,17)$$
$$(10,59049,223,74,62)$$
$$(10,59049,223,94,22)$$
$$(10,59049,225,90,18)$$
$$(10,59049,228,69,48)$$
$$(10,59049,228,84,3)$$
$$(10,59049,234,63,18)$$
$$(10,59049,237,48,24)$$
$$(10,59049,238,38,31)$$
$$(10,59049,238,46,17)$$
$$(10,59049,238,47,14)$$
$$(10,59049,238,49,2)$$
$$(10,59049,239,38,22)$$
$$(10,59049,241,22,22)$$
$$(10,59049,242,17,14)$$
$$(10,59049,242,22,1)$$
$$(10,59049,243,0,0)$$

Answer (score 1):

Proffering a special solution in your case of $3^n$ using quaternion algebra.

When $n$ is odd this is trivial.

When $n$ is even we can consider the quaternion
$$
q=2+2i+j.
$$
It has reduced norm $N(q)=2^2+2^2+1^2=9$, so we know that $N(q^\ell)=9^\ell$
for all integers $\ell$. Also, clearly the powers of $q$ belong to the Lipschitz order $\mathcal O_L=\Bbb{Z}\oplus\Bbb{Z}i\oplus \Bbb{Z}j\oplus\Bbb{Z}k.$

Let $u$ be the unit vector $u=(2i+j)/\sqrt5$. Because $u^2=-1$ (holds for all unit vectors $u$), it follows that  $\Bbb{C}_u:=\Bbb{R}\oplus \Bbb{R}u$ is a subring of the quaternions (actually it is isomorphic to the field of complex numbers, but we won't be needing that bit). Consequently $q^\ell\in\Bbb{C}_u$ for all integers $\ell$.

Therefore:

- The quaternion $q^\ell$ has integer coefficients, because those powers belong to the ring $\mathcal{O}_L$.
- When we write the quaternion power $$q^\ell=a_\ell+b_\ell i+c_\ell j+d_\ell k$$ with some integers $a_\ell,b_\ell, c_\ell, d_\ell$, we always have $d_\ell=0$, because $q^\ell\in\Bbb{C}_u$.
- Thus $$9^\ell=a_\ell^2+b_\ell^2+c_\ell^2$$ is a presentation of $9^\ell$ as a sum of three integers for all natural numbers $\ell$.

So we get
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\ell&a_\ell&b_\ell&c_\ell\\
\hline
1&2&2&1\\
2&-1&8&4\\
3&-22&14&7\\
4&-79&-16&-8\\
5&-118&-190&-95\\
6&239&-616&-308\\
7&2018&-754&-377
\end{array}
$$
Extend as you see fit.

---

The quaternion product rule of $q^{\ell+1}=q\cdot q^\ell$ translates to the following recurrence formula for the integers $a_\ell,b_\ell,c_\ell$:

- $a_{\ell+1}=2a_{\ell}-2b_{\ell}-c_{\ell}$,
- $b_{\ell+1}=2a_{\ell}+2b_{\ell}$,
- $c_{\ell+1}=2c_{\ell}+a_{\ell}$,
- And, as an extra, we shall always have $0=d_{\ell+1}=2c_{\ell}-b_{\ell}$ explaining the relation $b_\ell=2c_\ell$ easily spotted from the above table.

---

This approach obviously generalizes to powers of any sum of three squares - simply arrange the coefficient of $k$ to be zero. OTOH this is unlikely to lead to a list of ALL presentations as sums of three squares.

Comment: +1 At the moment only looking at prime powers $n = p^k$ where $p = 8k+7$ and $p=2$ are special cases.  For now just $p=3$.  At least I generate **one** solution, hopefully I can try to generate **all** solutions.

Comment: You can obviously alter the signs of the coefficients at any point as long as you observe the rule $b_\ell=2c_\ell$ to keep the products inside the subring $\Bbb{C}_u$.

Comment: We can possibly say more about this particular solution using the observation that $q=2+\sqrt{5}u$. Its powers behave exactly like those of $2+\sqrt5 i$. We simply need to split the imaginary parts (an integer multiple of $\sqrt5$) into orthogonal components with 2-to-1 ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on from my previous answer, I’ve found three more infinite families that can be generated from small solutions.
I now suspect these are just special cases of a more general parametric.
My apologies for any typos, I did this in a rush.

---

$$(2,9,2,2,1)$$
$$(4,81,6,6,3)$$
$$(6,729,18,18,9)$$
$$(8,6561,54,54,27)$$
$$(10,59049,162,162,81)$$
**$$(2c,3^2c,3^{c-1}*2,3^{c-1}*2,3^{c-1}), c>0$$**

---

$$(4,81,8,4,1)$$
$$(6,729,24,12,3)$$
$$(8,6561,72,36,9)$$
$$(10,59049,216,108,27)$$
**$$(2+2d,3^{2+2d},3^{d-1}*8,3^{d-1}*4,3^{d-1}), d>0$$**

---

$$(4,81,7,4,4)$$
$$(6,729,21,12,12)$$
$$(8,6561,63,36,36)$$
$$(10,59049,189,108,108)$$
**$$(2+2e,3^{2+2e},3^{e-1}*7,3^{e-1}*4,3^{e-1}*4), e>0$$**

---

**Update 29 Nov 2016.**

I’ve assumed and used the most obvious method of generating new solutions in my answers, but neglected to spot its generality; multiplying through by a constant $3^k$.

Sorry.

When $(q,n,x,y,z)$ is a solution, then new solutions are given by
$$(q+2k,3^{2k}n,3^kx,3^ky,3^kz)$$