# Find three numbers such that the sum of all three is a square and the sum of any two is a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

It seems like it should be a well known problem.  Ive read that Diophantine himself first posed it.  I couldnt find a solution when i researched for one.
It asks to find ordered triples $(x,y,z) $ such that 
$$x+y+z=a^2 $$
$$x+y=b^2$$
$$x+z=c^2$$
$$y+z=d^2$$

As an example  (41, 80, 320).  Any guidance is appreciated.  The ideal would be some kind of parametric solution for x, y, and z

Comment: [Does a Euler brick exist??](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiCzOfGg8HVAhUW24MKHYjYB9sQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEuler_brick&usg=AFQjCNESxHgxKlJUVO75x6QrwCHNs2bEpw)

Comment: @Nil: that is not accurate: here we do not need that $x,y,z$ are squares.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I just wanted to mention something related. Some times it is helpful to solve problems by looking at similar problems.

Comment: @Nil.   That's a cool reference.   Nonetheless I'm having trouble seeing how this helps.

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy it's a subset for the last three equations involving squares is one way. based on the equations alone you get,x,y and z must all be a difference of squares.

Comment: Amat, posted the solution to Jack's $u^2 + v^2 + w^2 = 2 a^2$ as an answer.

Comment: $17,32,32$ is the smaller with all positive entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the complete solution for multiplier 3 here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964607/when-will-a-parametric-solution-generate-all-possible-solutions/1965805#1965805

Back to 2:

With Jack's variables,  let $p+q+r+s$ be odd and $\gcd(p,q,r,s) = 1,$ then define
$$ a = p^2 + q^2 + r^2 + s^2,  $$
$$  u = 2(-pr + qr +ps+qs), $$
$$  v = p^2 - q^2 + r^2 - s^2 + 2 pq + 2rs,  $$
$$  w = p^2 - q^2 - r^2 + s^2 - 2 pq + 2rs.  $$
This gives
$$  u^2 + v^2 + w^2 = 2 a^2 $$
and **should give all primitive solutions**. Checking, and then proving, that these are all, takes longer than finding the formula.

Notice that $u \equiv 0 \pmod 4,$ because
$$ -pr + qr +ps+qs \equiv pr + qr +ps+qs \equiv (p+q)(r+s) \pmod 2. $$
As we demanded that $p+q+r+s$ be odd, it is not possible to have both $p+q$ and $r+s$ odd. One of  $p+q$ and $r+s$ is odd, while the other is even, meaning the product is even.

=================================

```
? a = p^2 + q^2 + r^2 + s^2
%1 = p^2 + (q^2 + (r^2 + s^2))
? 
? 
? u = 2 * ( -p * r + q * r + p * s + q * s    )
%2 = (-2*r + 2*s)*p + (2*r + 2*s)*q
? 
? v = p^2 - q^2 + r^2 - s^2 + 2 * p * q + 2 * r * s
%3 = p^2 + 2*q*p + (-q^2 + (r^2 + 2*s*r - s^2))
? 
? w = p^2 - q^2 - r^2 + s^2 - 2 * p * q + 2 * r * s
%4 = p^2 - 2*q*p + (-q^2 + (-r^2 + 2*s*r + s^2))
? 
? 
? 
? 
? u^2 + v^2 + w^2 - 2 * a^2
%5 = 0
? 
?
```

===========================

Raw search 2 a^2 = u^2 + v^2 + w^2, with odd a,v,w, even u, and v >= w.

```
  1       0   1   1
  3       4   1   1
  5       0   7   1
  5       4   5   3
  7       4   9   1
  7       8   5   3
  9       4  11   5
  9       8   7   7
 11       4  15   1
 11       8  13   3
 11      12   7   7
 13       0  17   7
 13       8  15   7
 13      12  13   5
 13      16   9   1
 15       8  19   5
 15      16  13   5
 15      20   7   1
 17       0  23   7
 17       4  21  11
 17       8  17  15
 17      20  13   3
 17      24   1   1
 19       4  25   9
 19      12  17  17
 19      12  23   7
 19      16  21   5
 19      24  11   5
 21       4  29   5
 21       8  23  17
 21      16  25   1
 21      20  19  11
 23       4  31   9
 23      12  25  17
 23      16  21  19
 23      24  19  11
 23      28  15   7
 23      32   5   3
 25       0  31  17
 25       4  35   3
 25       8  31  15
 25      20  27  11
 25      20  29   3
 25      24  25   7
 25      28  21   5
 25      32  15   1
 27       8  35  13
 27       8  37   5
 27      16  29  19
 27      20  23  23
 27      28  25   7
 29       0  41   1
 29       4  35  21
 29       8  33  23
 29      12  37  13
 29      20  29  21
 29      28  27  13
 29      36  19   5
 29      40   9   1
```

---

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
    a       u    v    w      p  q  r  s
    1       0    1    1      1  0  0  0
    3       4    1    1      0  1  1  1
    5       0    7    1      0  0  2  1
    5       0    7    1      0  0 -2 -1
    5       4    5    3      2  0 -1  0
    7       4    9    1      2  1  1  1
    7       8    5    3      1 -1 -2 -1
    9       4   11    5      2  0 -2 -1
    9       8    7    7      0  1  2  2
   11      12    7    7      3  0 -1  1
   11       4   15    1      3  1 -1  0
   11       8   13    3      3  1  0  1
   13       0   17    7      0  0  3  2
   13       0   17    7      0  0 -3 -2
   13      12   13    5      3  0 -2  0
   13      16    9    1      1  2  2  2
   13       8   15    7      2  1  2  2
   15      16   13    5      2 -1 -3 -1
   15      20    7    1      3  1 -1  2
   15       8   19    5      1  1  3  2
   17       0   23    7      4  1  0  0
   17      20   13    3      0  2  3  2
   17      24    1    1      3  0 -2  2
   17       4   21   11      2  0 -3 -2
   17       8   17   15      4  0 -1  0
   19      12   17   17      0  1  3  3
   19      12   23    7      3  0 -3 -1
   19      16   21    5      4  1 -1  1
   19      24   11    5      3 -1 -3  0
   19       4   25    9      4  1  1  1
   21      16   25    1      3  2  2  2
   21      20   19   11      4  1  0  2
   21       4   29    5      1  0 -4 -2
   21       8   23   17      4  0 -2 -1
   23      12   25   17      2  1  3  3
   23      16   21   19      3  1  2  3
   23      24   19   11      1  2  3  3
   23      28   15    7      3  2  1  3
   23      32    5    3      1  3  2  3
   23       4   31    9      3  1  3  2
   25       0   31   17      0  0  4  3
   25       0   31   17      0  0 -4 -3
   25      20   27   11      2 -1 -4 -2
   25      20   29    3      4  2  1  2
   25      24   25    7      4  0 -3  0
   25      28   21    5      1 -2 -4 -2
   25      32   15    1      2 -2 -4 -1
   25       4   35    3      2  1  4  2
   25       8   31   15      4  1  2  2
   27      16   29   19      1 -1 -4 -3
   27      20   23   23      5  0 -1  1
   27      28   25    7      3 -1 -4 -1
   27       8   35   13      5  1 -1  0
   27       8   37    5      4  1 -3 -1
   29       0   41    1      5  2  0  0
   29      12   37   13      3  0 -4 -2
   29      20   29   21      5  0 -2  0
   29      28   27   13      0  2  4  3
   29      36   19    5      4  2  0  3
   29      40    9    1      3 -2 -4  0
   29       4   35   21      2  0 -4 -3
   29       8   33   23      4  0 -3 -2
    a       u    v    w      p  q  r  s
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: Hey I know it's been a while, but how does one come up with your $(p,q,r,s)$ parameterization?  Or should I study the post you linked in your answer?

Comment: @AmateurMathPirate see my page http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/  especially  http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Jones_Pall_1939.pdf   and http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Pall_Automorphs_1940.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $$2a^2 = u^2+v^2+w^2$$
holds for some $(a,u,v,w)\in\mathbb{N}^4$ and the system
$$ \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}y+z&=& u^2 \\ x+z&=&v^2 \\ x+y&=&w^2\end{array}\right. $$
has integer solutions. Then we are done, since $x+y+z=a^2$.
If $u,v,w$ are even numbers the system clearly has integer solutions ($x=\frac{v^2+w^2-u^2}{2}$ and so on), so every triple $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\in\mathbb{N}^3$ such that $2(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2)$ is a square leads to a solution of the original problem. But, wait. If $2(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2)$ is a square it is an even square, i.e. a number of the form $4n^2$. In particular we get a solution of the original problem for every solution of the Diophantine equation $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2 = 2n^2$.

For instance, $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,n)=(0,1,7,5)$ leads to $2(10)^2 = 0^2+2^2+14^2$ and to the solution
$$ (x,y,z) = (-96,96,100). $$

The solution found by the OP, $(x,y,z)=(41,80,320)$, is associated with $11^2+19^2+20^2=2\cdot 21^2$. Another solution is $(x,y,z)=(-111,120,280)$, which is associated with $3^2+13^2+20^2=2\cdot 17^2$.

Comment: Also I generally do not know how to solve, diophantically, the equation $$2a^2=b^2+c^2+d^2$$. Any references or guidance on that?

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy: such solutions are associated with decompositions $2n^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$ where $a,b,c$ have roughly the same magnitude. For instance, $$(x,y,z)=(57,112,672)$$ is associated with $13^2+27^2+28^2=2\cdot 29^2$.

Comment: And by Legendre's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem), any number that is not of the form $4^k(8m+7)$ can be represented as the sum of three squares, so there are plenty of solutions.

Comment: Outstanding.   Your answer has shown me where I need to study.   Thank you.

Comment: one more thing,  can you spell out why "so every triple $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\in\mathbb{N}^3$ such that $2(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2)$ is a square leads to a solution of the original problem"?

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy: assume that $2a^2=4u^2+4v^2+4w^2$ holds and consider the system given by $x+y=4u^2$ and so on. This system has the integer solutions $x=2u^2+2v^2-2w^2$ and so on. It follows that $a^2=2(u^2+v^2+w^2)$ always leads to a solution of the original problem.

Comment: Jack, all primitive solutions of $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 2 d^2$ can be parametrized by $\bar{q} v q,$ where $v$ is a quaternion with real part zero and norm 2, such as $v = i+j;$ meanwhile, $d$ is the norm of $q.$ Here is multiplier 3: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964607/when-will-a-parametric-solution-generate-all-possible-solutions/1965805#1965805

Comment: @WillJagy: that is a nice addendum! So quaternions show that there is a bijection between the rational points on the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ and the primitive solutions of the given problem, correct?

Comment: Jack, added computer output to my answer, with some choices to reduce repetition in the parametrized output. Works fine. Oh, notice in the earlier answer with multiplier 3, Tito's answer gives the final variable as the sum of three squares; the problem is that this is never $7 \pmod 8,$ so infinitely many solutions are missing. That is the problem with stereographic projection.

Comment: Dear friend Jack: I did not know this problem that I proposed today (I already delete it). The infinity of solutions comes out of a single $ (x, y, z) $ with multiplication by $ n ^ 2 $. Call a solution "primary" if it does not have a common square factor. Are there an infinity of primary solutions? Note that  $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2 = 2n^2$ this does not guarantee that the sum of two of them be a square. Regards (I always like your answers).

Answer (score 2):

A family of solutions can be obtained from
\begin{eqnarray*}
x&=&48m^2+8m+1 \\
y&=&96m^2+16m \\
z&=&16m(6m+1)(6m^2+m-1)
\end{eqnarray*}
One can easily verify that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x+y&=&(12m+1)^2 \\
x+z&=&(24m^2+4m-1)^2 \\
y+z&=&(4m(6m+1))^2 \\
x+y+z&=&(24m^2+4m+1)^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

For the General case of formula there.  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1172008_combinations_of_numbers_in_squares

The system of equations:

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&a+b=x^2\\&a+c=y^2\\&b+c=z^2\\&a+b+c=q^2\end{aligned}\right.$$

Solutions have the form:

$$a=4t((2t-p)k^2+2(2t-p)^2k-2p^3+9tp^2-14pt^2+8t^3)$$

$$b=4(p^2-3pt+2t^2)k^2+8(4t^3-8pt^2+5tp^2-p^3)k+$$

$$+4(p^4-6tp^3+15p^2t^2-18pt^3+8t^4)$$

$$c=k^4+4(2t-p)k^3+4(p^2-3pt+3t^2)k^2-8(p^2-3pt+2t^2)tk+$$

$$+4t(2p^3-9tp^2+14pt^2-7t^3)$$

$$x=2(2t-p)(k+2t-p)$$

$$y=k^2+2(2t-p)k+2t^2$$

$$z=k^2+2(2t-p)k+2(t-p)^2$$

$$q=k^2+2(2t-p)k+6t^2-6tp+2p^2$$

$k,t,p$ - integers asked us.