# Given $m$, find three numbers $a,b,c$ such that $c-b=m(b-a)$ and $a+b,a+c,b+c$ are all squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I've worked with the next problem

- Given an integer $m$, find three integers $a,b,c$, with $b\neq a$, such that $c-b=m(b-a)$ and 
  $$a+b=x^2, \ \ a+c=y^2, \ \ b+c=z^2,$$
  where $x,y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I've not been able to give a result that guarantees the existence of solutions of this problem for some $m$ values.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ given as part of the problem, or only $m$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383893/find-three-numbers-such-that-the-sum-of-all-three-is-a-square-and-the-sum-of-any

Comment: Only $m$ is given

Comment: In that case $a=b=c=2$ works for every $m$.

Comment: I forgot to say that $b$ should be different of $a$.

Comment: The condition requires $$y^2-x^2=m(z^2-y^2)$$ or $$x^2-(m+1)y^2=-mz^2.$$ 

You also require $x+y+z$ even, and then you get $$a=\frac{x^2+y^2-z^2}{2},b=\frac{x^2+z^2-y^2}{2},c=\frac{y^2+z^2-x^2}{2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

The condition requires $$y^2-x^2=m(z^2-y^2)$$ or $$x^2-(m+1)y^2=-mz^2.$$

You also require $x+y+z$ even, and then you get $$a=\frac{x^2+y^2-z^2}{2},b=\frac{x^2+z^2-y^2}{2},c=\frac{y^2+z^2-x^2}{2}.$$

But there is a general approach to finding all rational solutions to:

$$aX^2+bY^2=c$$

if you have one rational solution.

Here, we have $(a,b,c)=(1,-(m+1),-m)$. and base solution $(X_0,Y_0)=(1,1)$.

Then if $p,q$ are integers, not both zero, then there is another rational solution $(X,Y)=(X_0+pt,Y_0+qt)$ with $t\neq 0$.

Solving, we get $$(1+pt)^2-(m+1)(1+qt)^2=-m\\
2pt + p^2t^2  -2(m+1)qt-(m+1)q^2t^2=0\\
2t\left[p-q(m+1)\right] + t^2\left[p^2-(m+1)q^2\right]=0$$

Assuming $t\neq 0$, you have:

$$t=\frac{2q(m+1)-2p}{p^2-(m+1)q^2}$$

This obviously has problems if $p^2-(m+1)q^2=0$, which can happen when $m+1$ is a perfect square.

Also, if $q=1,p=m+1$ then the numerator is zero, so doesn't give a new solution, but that's okay.

Now $$1+pt = \frac{(m+1)q(2p-q)-p^2}{p^2-(m+1)q^2}\\
1+qt=\frac{(m+1)q^2+p(p-2q)}{p^2-(m+1)q^2}
$$

Then any time $(m+1)q+p$ is even, and $p^2-(m+1)q^2\neq 0$ you get the solution:

$$(x,y,z)=\left((m+1)q(2p-q)-p^2,(m+1)q^2+p(p-2q),p^2-(m+1)q^2\right)$$

Trying $(p,q)=(4,2)$ you get:

$$(x,y,z)=(6m+2,2m+2,6-2m)\\(a,b,c)=(18m^2+4m-14,18m^2-28m+18,-14m^2+4m+18)$$

The general formula gives (I think, still needs checking):

$$a=2\left[(q-2p)^2q^2(m+1)^2-(4q^2-6qp+4p^2)pq(m+1)+p^2(p-2q)^2\right]\\
b=2\left[(q-2p)^2q^2(m+1)^2-(4p^2-2pq+4q^2)pq(m+1)+(p^2+4pq-4q^2)p^2\right]\\
c=2\left[(q^2+4pq-4p^2)q^2(m+1)^2+(4p^2+6pq+4q^2)pq(m+1)+p^2(p+2q)^2\right]
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let 
\begin{eqnarray*}
a&=&2((mp^2+2mpq-q^2)^2+(mp^2+q^2)^2-(-mp^2+2pq+q^2)^2) \\
b&=&2((mp^2+2mpq-q^2)^2-(mp^2+q^2)^2+(-mp^2+2pq+q^2)^2) \\
c&=&2(-(mp^2+2mpq-q^2)^2+(mp^2+q^2)^2+(-mp^2+2pq+q^2)^2) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
One can easily verify that
\begin{eqnarray*}
a+b&=& 4(mp^2+2mpq-q^2)^2 \\
b+c&=&4(-mp^2+2pq+q^2)^2 \\
c+a&=&4(mp^2+q^2)^2 \\
c-b&=&-16(pm-q)(p+q) pqm \\
b-a&=&-16(pm-q)(p+q) pq.
\end{eqnarray*}