# Finding every solution of $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$ in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms, parametrization, gaussian-integers

Specifically, $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}(i)$ are complex numbers with rational parts whose squares sum to $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$. There's an answer to this question over $\mathbb{Q}$ already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964607) but I couldn't find any more information.

Like, does the parametrization over $\mathbb{Q}$ still give you all solutions over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ if you let the parameters vary over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Here's the substitutions for the parametrization from the linked post:
$$a=\frac{r^2+s^2-t^2-2t(r+s)}{r^2+s^2+t^2}\quad b=\frac{r^2-s^2+t^2-2s(r+t)}{r^2+s^2+t^2}\quad c=\frac{-r^2+s^2+t^2-2r(s+t)}{r^2+s^2+t^2}$$
$$r=\frac{1}{b-1}\quad s=\frac{1}{c-1}\quad t=\frac{a-1}{(b-1)(c-1)}$$

My next bet is to try to find research papers on complex ternary quadratic forms. Either that or to try to do something with "pure" quaternions which I don't really understand.

I also spent some time studying the proof for the parametrization of Pythagorean triples over both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and feel pretty comfortable with it. But I couldn't find anything there that was adaptable to this diophantine problem.

I did notice that you can scale the equation into $a^2+b^2+c^2=3d^2$ over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ by clearing denominators. And that this rearranges to
$$(a+bi)(a-bi)=(\sqrt{3}d+c)(\sqrt{3}d-c)$$
which gives a factorization of one number in two ways and that seems useful. But this would be a factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[i,\sqrt{3}]$ which might be useless as unique factorization might be messed up. Some other readings made it seem like $\mathbb{Z}[i,\sqrt{3}]$ is actually just the cyclotomic ring $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{12}]$ in disguise so I thought to spend some effort on that connection eventually.

Any guidance or help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: yes,   the stereographic projection also works over $\mathbb Q[i]$ although it is a bit messier to see when $r^2 + s^2 + t^2$  is nonzero. I will need to think about how well my answer generalizes; that is, my recipe gives some correct answers to $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 3 d^2,$ but I'm not sure it gives all  answers in $\mathbb Z[i].$   Meanwhile, I put stuff at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/

Comment: I will leave in the zeros in the formulas for $a,b,c.$ They serve as spacers.

$$ a = w^2 + x^2 - y^2 - z^2 + 0 \, w  x - 2  w  y + 2  x  y + 2  w  z + 2  x  z + 0  \,  y  z $$
$$ b = w^2 - x^2 + y^2 - z^2 + 2  w  x - 0  \,  w  y + 2  x  y - 2  w  z + 0  \,  x  z + 2  y  z$$
$$ c = w^2 - x^2 - y^2 + z^2 - 2  w  x + 2  w  y + 0  \,  x  y + 0  \,  w  z + 2  x  z + 2  y  z$$
$$ d = w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 $$

Comment: anyway, the point of my answer was finding all primitive integer solutions, meaning $\gcd(a,b,c,d) = 1.$  Extra work to deal with the desired condition in $\mathbb Z[i]$  and not something I've done ahead of time

Comment: What is the problem with adapting the parametrization by stereographic projection to $\Bbb{Q}(i)$?